# Spring MongoDB Java driver 1.4.1 raises exception "replication is shutting down" on save when primary service fails over

Tags: spring, mongodb

Java Mongo Driver 1.4.1 Four node Replicaset with one arbiter / failover test

Exception is:

```
Query failed with error code 11600 and error message 'interrupted at shutdown' on server
```

The mongo driver fails with the following on mongo save, but the election goes fine on mongo database finishing subsequent to the java exception. Exception occurs between the primary stepping down, and a new primary being elected.

How do I prevent the following stacktrace on mongo save using driver or replicaset connection settings? Is it possible for the driver to wait sufficient time for the election, or do I need to reopen the connection?

I've tried everything. Should I just reopen the connection or should increasing/decreasing defaulted `electionTimelimitMillis` and `heartbeatTimeoutMillis` on replicaset, and increasing `connectionTimeout`, `serverSelectionTimeout` in java or other setting be used to ensure the driver waits for a secondary to be elected primary. The mongodb itself does the election properly but by that time the mongo save has bombed out.

I've also tried to run a ping from driver to database to spot the primary is down a bit quicker.

Here's the full stack trace :

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 11600: 'interrupted at shutdown' on server xxxx:999. 
The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "interrupted at shutdown", "code" : 11600, "codeName" : "InterruptedAtShutdown" }
    at com.mongodb.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:115)
    at com.mongodb.connection.WriteCommandProtocol.receiveMessage(WriteCommandProtocol.java:240)
    at com.mongodb.connection.WriteCommandProtocol.execute(WriteCommandProtocol.java:104)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InsertCommandProtocol.execute(InsertCommandProtocol.java:67)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InsertCommandProtocol.execute(InsertCommandProtocol.java:37)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:159)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:286)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.insertCommand(DefaultServerConnection.java:115)
    at com.mongodb.operation.InsertOperation.executeCommandProtocol(InsertOperation.java:76)
    at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation$1.call(BaseWriteOperation.java:141)
    at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation$1.call(BaseWriteOperation.java:133)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:230)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:221)
    at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation.execute(BaseWriteOperation.java:133)
    at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation.execute(BaseWriteOperation.java:60)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:781)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:764)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.executeWriteOperation(DBCollection.java:333)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:328)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:319)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:289)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:255)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:177)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.save(DBCollection.java:398)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.save(DBCollection.java:373)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$11.doInCollection(MongoTemplate.java:1085)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:462)
```